# How can I hide/show textboxes based on drop down menu selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down menu for which one option is 'Other'.  Each option is tored in a table with an id ie `if OptionId = 6, OptionDescription is "Other"`.

If 'Other' is chosen, a text box should appear for the user to enter specifically what the other criteria is:

```
<tr>
    <td class="labels">
        Option:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <%=Html.DropDownList("OptionId", Utilities.OptionLookup(), "-Select One-") %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="OtherOption" type="text"  />
    </td>
</tr>
```

In this case, `Utilities.OptionLookup()` gets the values from my Option table and populates the `dd`.  At the moment, I just have a a plain textbox `OtherOption`.

I've used javascript before to do something like this but it's based on a click event. So, I set the text box to `'display:none'`, use `onclick` to name my script and do the visible true or false in my script.

I want to be able to do something similar but when 'Other' is selected in my drop down.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the same way, but instead of the `onclick` event, you utilize the [`onchange`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange) event.

Comment: It was a bit more work than that but, essentially, that's the answer.